# accessing id of a label's "for" attribute

Tags: jquery

I have a JSF application that produces a page with a label on it:

```
<label for="_idJsp0:question" class="left">Question</label>
```

And then elsewhere in the DOM is the component:

```
<td><textarea rows="7" cols="25" id="_idJsp0:question" name="_idJsp0:question">My Question.</textarea></td>
```

For Selenium, I am building a custom location strategy using jQuery, and so my question is how do return the ID of the label's "for" attribute?  I can use .attr("for") on the label to return the string of the ID but I am missing how to actually return properly formatted selector output.  I've tried approaches like:

```
var inner = "label:contains('Question')";
$('#' + $(document).find(inner).attr('for'));
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It's the colon on the id that is keeping the selector from working. The text after the colon is interpreted as a meta-class instead of as a part of the id.

You have to escape the colon in the selector:

```
$('#' + $(document).find(inner).attr('for').replace(':', '\\:'))
```

For completeness; if you want to escape any special character in an identifier in a selector you would use a replace like this

```
id.replace(/([!"#$%&'\(\)\*\+,\.\/:;<=>\?@\[\\\]\^`\{\|\}~])/g, '\\$1')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the special jQuery selectors.
Try something like this:

```
function jqescape(str) { 
    return str.replace(/[#;&,\.\+\*~':"!\^\$\[\]\(\)=>|\/\\]/g, '\\$&'); 
}
var inner = "label:contains('Question')";
$('#' + jqescape( $(document).find(inner).attr('for') ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

This will print "My Question":

```
alert($("textarea[id='" + 
    $("label:contains('Question')").attr('for') + 
    "']").html());
```

It's looking for `[id='xxx']` instead of `#xxx` because there's a `:` in the ID.  But `:` is a special character in [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).